# foreign key constraint fails while importing

Tags: mysql, database, import, workbench

I am getting this error ONLY with MySQL Workbench, but when I import it MANUALLY in the console it works (with the content of the .sql file) then it is working NORMALLY..the issue is that this .sql file is very very big and I can't paste so much into the commandline (chrome would crash ect)..so I have to use MySQL Workbench..

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE list_countries (
  country_code CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  country_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (country_code)
);


INSERT INTO list_countries (country_code, country_name) VALUES
('A1', 'Anonymous Proxy'),
('A2', 'Satellite Provider'),
('AD', 'Andorra');


CREATE TABLE list_ipv4 ( 
  range_start INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  range_end INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  country_code CHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
  banned INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
  PRIMARY KEY (range_start, range_end, country_code), 
  CONSTRAINT fk_ipv4_countrycode 
    FOREIGN KEY (country_code) 
    REFERENCES list_countries (country_code) 
    ON DELETE RESTRICT 
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT 
);
```

Content (ONLY some first lines) of the .sql file I am trying to import with MySQL Workbench:

```
INSERT INTO list_ipv4 (range_start, range_end, country_code) VALUES (16777216, 16777471, 'AU'),
(16777472, 16778239, 'CN'),
(16778240, 16779263, 'AU');
```

> ERROR Message: ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 1: Cannot add or update a
>   child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`samp`.`list_ipv4`,
>   CONSTRAINT `fk_ipv4_countrycode` FOREIGN KEY (`country_code`)
>   REFERENCES `list_countries` (`country_code`))
>
> Operation failed with exitcode 1

Please help :/

Comment: thank you very much for the edit :)

Comment: What does `SHOW INNODB STATUS` print out after you use the query? Most of the time this will give you a beter error message.

Comment: It's better to set the engine within the create table statements... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-engine-setting.html .. then you never get in trouble when the MySQL's engine is different

Comment: yea i am getting an error message :/ seems like i have to give it up, since I am a beginner with MySQL...but thank you for your help :)